# rundeck loses track of Job

Tags: rundeck

I'm having an issue with rundeck.
I'm running rundeck version 2.10.4 with the default file-based data storage

For one particular environment, if the job takes longer than 1h ( approximative observation ), the jobs stays at "Running" forever.
After that 1h or so period, the jobs log aren't recovered anymore in the rundeck job's log output.
When the job eventualy ends on the distant server, I am forced to kill the job manually on rundeck.

I can't seem to find anything relevant in rundeck's log files

The jobs i'm running are on distant environments.
It doesn't happen on every environment. The one i'm having issues with is in a different network zone (don't know if it matters).

I was having the same situation with my former 2.6.1 version of rundeck.

any clue?

thanks

Comment: Could you post code snippets or explain what kind of tasks you are running?

Comment: I'm running shell scripts that launch a java batch. Same jobs that works fine on other env

Comment: I see the same problem. The script is still running on the server, and I know it's not stuck because I see new child processes from the parent being spawned, but log output on runback has stopped (each new child process should produce new log output).

Comment: err, *rundeck* not runback..